# Is it possible to store the summary of an eRm model?

Tags: r

I am using the eRm package to estimate a Rasch model. The RM() function returns a Rasch model that I can summarize using the summary() function.  However, when I try to store the results, R creates an empty object.

```
library(eRm) 
my_data <- matrix(sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE), nrow = 10)

my_model <- RM(X = my_data)
summary(my_model)
my_summary <- summary(my_model)
```

Why does this operation not work in this case but does work when storing the summary of a linear model? Is there another way to store the summary of the eRm model?

Comment: Perhaps the result of `summary(my_model)` is just a print statement, which cannot be saved. You might have a look at the code in `summary.RM` if `RM(X = my_data)` produces an object of type RM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Imo surmised, it looks like `summary.eRm` just prints to the console, rather than returning an object. You can inspect the code for `summary.eRm` by running `getAnywhere(summary.eRm)`. `summary` is a "generic" function, meaning that what it does depends on what "method" is called when the function is invoked.

For an `lm` model object, when you type `summary(my_model)`, the `summary.lm` function is dispatched. But when you type `summary(my_model)` and `my_model` is an `eRm` object, the `summary.eRm` method is dispatched. `summary.lm` returns an object, but `summary.eRm` just prints to the console. Run `methods(summary)` to see the various summary functions that get dispatched for different types of objects.

A workaround would be to create your own summary object (or a function to create such an object), using the model object itself. You can inspect the components of the model object with `str(my_model)`. You can also look at the code for `summary.eRm` to see where it is getting each of the components that it prints to the console.

Here's a simple example, lifting code from `summary.eRm` to create a summary function:

```
RMsmry = function(obj) {

  cols = c("Estimate", "Std. Error", "lower CI", "upper CI")

  # Create difficulty summary
  ci = confint(obj, "eta")
  tbl1 = as.data.frame(cbind(round(obj$etapar, 3), 
                             round(obj$se.eta, 3), round(ci, 3)))
  names(tbl1) = cols

  # Create easiness summary
  ci <- confint(obj, "beta")
  tbl2 = as.data.frame(cbind(round(obj$betapar, 3), 
                             round(obj$se.beta, 3), round(ci, 3)))
  names(tbl2) = cols

  return(list(Difficulty=tbl1, Easiness=tbl2))
}

my_summary = RMsmry(my_model)
my_summary
```

> ```
> $Difficulty
>     Estimate Std. Error lower CI upper CI
> I2    -1.191      0.658   -2.480    0.098
> I3    -1.191      0.658   -2.480    0.098
> I4     0.078      0.627   -1.150    1.306
> I5    -0.750      0.623   -1.971    0.471
> I6     0.078      0.627   -1.150    1.306
> I7     1.079      0.748   -0.386    2.544
> I8    -0.339      0.614   -1.543    0.865
> I9     0.078      0.627   -1.150    1.306
> I10    1.079      0.748   -0.386    2.544
>
> $Easiness
>          Estimate Std. Error lower CI upper CI
> beta I1    -1.079      0.748   -2.544    0.386
> beta I2     1.191      0.658   -0.098    2.480
> beta I3     1.191      0.658   -0.098    2.480
> beta I4    -0.078      0.627   -1.306    1.150
> beta I5     0.750      0.623   -0.471    1.971
> beta I6    -0.078      0.627   -1.306    1.150
> beta I7    -1.079      0.748   -2.544    0.386
> beta I8     0.339      0.614   -0.865    1.543
> beta I9    -0.078      0.627   -1.306    1.150
> beta I10   -1.079      0.748   -2.544    0.386
> ```